# Как окрасить в цвет кусок полосы между двумя бегунками?

Tags: javascript, slider, rangeslider

Написал свой ranged selector на чистом JS. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать выделение цветом пространства между двух ползунков?

Вот код:

```
var sliderElem = document.getElementById('range');
var thumbMin = document.getElementById('thumb-min');
var thumbMax = document.getElementById('thumb-max');
// var thumbMin = sliderElem.children[0];
var sliderCoords = getCoords(sliderElem);
var rangeEnd = sliderElem.offsetWidth - thumbMin.offsetWidth;
// var rangeEnd = sliderElem.offsetWidth;

var min = parseInt(getComputedStyle(thumbMin).left);
var max = parseInt(getComputedStyle(thumbMax).left);

console.log(parseInt(min), parseInt(max));
//минимум - 18, максимум - 48

thumbMin.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var thumbCoords = getCoords(thumbMin);
    var shiftX = e.pageX - thumbCoords.left;


    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        var newLeft = e.pageX - shiftX - sliderCoords.left;

        //если вне слайдера
        if (newLeft < 0) {
            newLeft = 0;
        }

        if (newLeft > max - thumbMin.offsetWidth / 2) {
            newLeft = max - thumbMin.offsetWidth / 2;
        }

        min = newLeft;
        thumbMin.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
    }

    document.onmouseup = function() {
        console.log(getCoords(thumbMin));
        console.log(min);
        document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
    }

    return false;
};

thumbMax.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var thumbCoords = getCoords(thumbMax);
    var shiftX = e.pageX - thumbCoords.left;

    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        var newLeft = e.pageX - shiftX - sliderCoords.left;

        //если вне слайдера
        if (newLeft < min + thumbMin.offsetWidth / 2) {
            newLeft = min + thumbMin.offsetWidth / 2;
        }

        if (newLeft > rangeEnd) {
            newLeft = rangeEnd;
        }
        max = newLeft;

        thumbMax.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
    }

    document.onmouseup = function() {
        console.log(getCoords(thumbMax));
        console.log(max);
        document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
    }

    return false;
};

thumbMin.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
};

function getCoords(elem) {
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    return {
        top: box.top + pageYOffset,
        left: box.left + pageXOffset
    };
}
```

Comment: добавте `html` в вопрос

Comment: и CSS тоже добавьте

Comment: утром будет сделано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выкрасить в цвет часть блока, имея несвязанные элементы не получится, ну можно использовать canvas и прочую магию, но я бы посоветовал вам попробовать вот что.

Делаем div, добавляем ему "ползунки" в :after и :before, сам див делаем absolute красим в цвет, не забываем высоту.

Вешаем обработчики на ползунки, которые при перетаскивании меняют диву style.left и style.right.

Вот так, конечно при усложнении задачи необходимо допилить в соответствии с требованиями, но по другому закрасить будет ещё сложнее и запутаннее.

Comment: А разве одновременное влияние на style.left и style.right позволят растянуть блок?

Comment: да, если он position: absolute

Comment: Спасибо, прекрасно сработало